# When were brains seen as computers for the first time?

Tags: neuroscience

Let me state firstly that I don't think that the nervous system is a computer.
Not down up, nor top down.  On top of that, brains cannot truly be separated from the body.

I am curious still.  Who were the first people to think that the brain is a  computer?
Today this view can be found in mind philosophers like Hofstadter.

Comment: *On top of that, brains cannot truly be be separated from the body.* --- Then simply consider the entire physical apparatus (body, brain, whatever) as the computer. Anyway, surely [Laplace's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon) (1814) is a lower bound for how far back. Probably also [**Theoria Philosophiae Naturalis**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Theoria+philosophiae+naturalis%22+%22computer%22+Boscovich) by Boscovich (1758) would qualify.

Comment: Aside from precursors analogizing minds and bodies to "machines" since early mechanists like Hobbes in the 17th century, the more concrete modern theory is contemporaneous with the rise of electronic computers:"*Warren McCulloch and Walter Pitts (1943) first suggested that something resembling the Turing machine might provide a good model for the mind. In the 1960s, Turing computation became central to the emerging interdisciplinary initiative cognitive science...*", [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-mind/#ClaComTheMin).

Comment: If somebody were to build a functioning, electronic simulacrum of a human brain, we probably would not call it a "computer," but the engineers probably would recognize it as "computing machinery."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ineed "if". This only happens in thought.